How to force OpencasCAD use desktop OpenGL?
I have an occ view embedded in a qt app,
and it works fine under Windows like this:

but under ubuntu, App UI got messed up likes this:

and at the same time, two lines warnings got repeated forever:
2024-12-31 17:46:19 [Warning]: QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x5ecb89d98a80
2024-12-31 17:46:19 [Warning]: QRhiGles2: Failed to make context current. Expect bad things to happen.
2024-12-31 17:46:19 [Warning]: QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x5ecb89d990a0
2024-12-31 17:46:19 [Warning]: QRhiGles2: Failed to make context current. Expect bad things to happen.
2024-12-31 17:46:19 [Warning]: QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x5ecb89d87dc0
2024-12-31 17:46:19 [Warning]: QRhiGles2: Failed to make context current. Expect bad things to happen.
.....

And if removing OCC related stuff, App UI works fine(under ubuntu) without any warnings.
Since occ view still works, I doubt that OCC caused this problem.
Because based on warning message,the Gles2 is used,
and this type of opengl API should be used in a mobile environment,
but my ubuntu run inside a desktop machine. I have tried to:
1, Add:
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL);

as first line of main function.
2, Add/delete:
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts);

as second line of main function.
but same errors still exist, so questions are:
1, How can I make sure whether Gles2 cause this problem?
2, If Gles2 do cause this problem, how to force OCC use desktop OpenGL?
